# Cannot get euro sign to show in html browser, despite using &euro;

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show a euro sign in a html page. I am using Chrome, and it is still coming up Attraction cost: €38.00. I obviously want a euro sign instead here.

The line of code I am changing is the line below. It is javascript, and to give context I am creating a list of tourist attractions and their prices, and using javascript to display the data coming from a database

```
attractionCost.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Attraction cost: ' + '&euro;' + entry.cost ));
```

If anyone has any ideas why the euro sign isn't being displayed can you please let me know. Thanks

Comment: `&euro;` is an HTML entity, but you're creating a text node, so there's no HTML interpretation/parsing. Instead use an actual unicode character or escape sequence,

Comment: @clockwork What is a unicode character or escape sequence?

Comment: `document.createTextNode('Attraction cost: \u20ac' + entry.cost )` Uses unicode escape sequence for that character.

Comment: `document.createTextNode('Attraction cost: €' + entry.cost )` Uses the character directly.

Comment: @clockwork thank you very much! :) This worked great. Using the character directly didn't work ( I did have this to start with) But the first option you gave worked great

Comment: If the `€` didn't work, I think that could be due to the character encoding of your JavaScript file.